# Ejecutar un comando de cmd desde un programa Java

Tags: java, cmd

Hola estoy tratando de ejecutar un .bat desde java, que tiene un comando y debe crear un archivo con la salida, el .bat funciona correctamente, el problema lo tengo al invocarlo desde el programa java ya que no espera a que finalice y mi archivo se crea sin contenido.
También he probado a ejecutar el comando directamente si el .bat y me pasa lo mismo.
Estoy probando así, pero no funciona, alguna idea?? muchas gracias :)
 Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

```
        try {
            p.waitFor();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Además de `p.waitfor();` intenta meter todo lo anterior en el try. No se si te servirá, pero al menos, te dirá en el catch que error tienes. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no hay ningún error, el problema que existe es que el .bat tarda en acabar y no se espera a terminar la ejecución por lo tanto el archivo que quiero crear esta vacio.

Comment: @Silvia Para poder visualizar algo cmd tienes que usar un  System.out.println("Hola"); con el resultado del metodo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas usar /wait para mantener abierto el proceso hasta que el .bat acabe

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start /wait path.bat");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era esto lo que buscaba :)